# Is it grammatical to use the definite article in these two cases?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Kindly have a look at the following paragraph:

> The Grade 11 English Text aims to develop students' reading and writing skills and at the same time provides opportunities to improve *the* listening skills.
>
> The main objectives of the text are:
>   (a) to build up and enrich the vocabulary of *the* learners
>   (b) to train learners to do as much independent reading as possible 
>   (c) to expose learners to a variety of contemporary English writing 
>   (d) to help learners assimilate the grammar, lexis, syntax and idiom ...

I think the *the* before "listening skills" and the one after "vocabulary of" are superfluous.

Is there a grammatical rule that might pertain to these two usages and say with more certainty whether they are grammatical (or just idiomatic)?

Comment: I find the first one very unnatural—but then that entire sentence is quite poorly written. The second one is superfluous in that you can remove it without changing the meaning, but I find it neither unnatural nor conspicuous where it is.

Comment: In the context of teaching materials, all of the constructions seem very natural. For example, the substitution of "learners" for "students" carries a sensitivity to "needs." The lengthening of the first sentence, which could be pared down to "The Grade 11 English Text aims to develop ("aims to" could also go) students' reading, writing and listening skills,"  implies a bonus: Not only will you get reading and writing, but if you call this number right away, we'll toss in Listening Skills for free!

Comment: You can argue that they are superfluous, but that doesn't make them ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The first *the* would be better replaced with *their*, whose antecedent is clearly *students'*. Whose reading and writing skills? The students'. Whose listening skills? The students'. I'm not sure it's a *grammar* error, but it is at the very least awkward.

I like the second *the*: it implies that the objectives apply only to a certain subset of all possible learners (in this case, Grade 11 students). (I have a bigger problem with the noun *learners*; students sounds both more natural to my ear, *and* was used in the first sentence. Switching from *students* to *learners* in the second sentence just feels awkward).

Comment: Please notice that the writer switches to the generic "learners" (without 'the' ) in list item (b) although he is still referring to the same "learners". And he continues to use the generic "learners" without 'the' in the sentences that follows it. Doesn't that switch-back to generic reference invalidate the use of 'the' above?

Comment: I can't give any concrete rule (and I deleted a discussion of this point from my initial draft), but in (a) "learners" serves as a prepositional object while in (b)-(d) it is the direct object of an infinitive. At least to my ear, you could use "the" or not in (b)-(d), but dropping it in (a) sounds awkward.

Comment: Than Oo: Here you get into the murky "understood" rule where at the author's discretion a modifier may be dropped if the reader understands that the modifier has been firmly established and doesn't need repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Saying (writing) "the learners" implies that you already have a particular group or set in mind. I think in this context " students " would be more appropriate. Same goes for " the listening skills"...

Answer (score -1):

As the definite article, "the" provides specificity or emphasis. By attaching the to a plural noun, the implication is a larger group exists:

I like chocolates. I like the chocolates.

Emphasis:

Everyone may leave class, except the boys.

But in your first example, "listening skills" don't seem to require either function of the (what different group of listening skills could "the" listening skills refer to?), so I'd agree that "the" is superfluous.

The second example is a little trickier. It's conceivable that in the English class, there are some students who are English Language Learners (students whose first language is not English), so the teacher wants to emphasize vocabulary building for "the learners." But that doesn't seem to be the case here, so again "the" is superfluous.

So, superfluous, but grammatical.